# Copying values from one sheet to another using a search range for criteria entered

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am looking for some assistance... Below is a code and some images of what I am attempting to acheive. I have created a selector which when you enter a qty. I want it to take the line with the quantity included and take it to another sheet on the next available line. My code is not yielding an error but neither is it doing anything at all.

I wish to take range J:P of the line with a qty entered and then paste it into the other worksheet in the next blank row of column D as there will be entries already included in A-C. Can anyone here help?

```
    Sub Add()

    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim mysearch As Integer
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Output")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Selector")
    iRow = Sheets("Output").Range("D2").End(xlUp) + 1

    mysearch = Sheets("Selector").Range("N10").Value

    With Sheets("Selector")
        Set searchRange = Sheets("Selector").Range("N12:N35") ', .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        ws1.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -4).Value       
'and so on
    End If

    End Sub
```

This is the selector
[image]

This is where I would like to paste the values (in a different order).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, I've simply amended your code slightly, and I believe it should work as expected:

```
Sub Add()
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim mysearch As Integer
    Dim iRow As Long, Last As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Output")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Selector")

    iRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Last = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

    mysearch = ws2.Range("N10").Value

    Set foundCell = ws2.Range("N12:N" & Last).Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        ws1.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = foundCell.Offset(0, -4).Value
    End If

End Sub
```